# htaccess rewrite rule adding and removing parts plus 301 redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've just converted a phpNuke CMS to WordPress. After the conversion was done, I noticed that there were two URLs for each post. This is the pattern I converted:

```
www.domain.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=1
```

Unfortunately, there is another URL like this:

```
www.domain.com/1.htm
```

Now I need a rewrite rule that adds "modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=" and removes ".htm" at the same time and makes a 301 redirect.

Now I use a quick and dirty workaround like that:

```
RedirectPermanent /8.htm http://domain.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=8
```

That's quick and easy, but far from elegant with 1600 posts. And it might slow down the page.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex in your rule and have just single rule to handle all these URLs:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]+)\.html?$ /modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=$1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The rule works for 8.htm, but not for, say, 123.htm. The posts have consecutive numbers from 8.htm to 1679.htm.

Comment: see updated code and make sure to test this in a new browser. It will work for `8.htm OR 1679.htm`